# Custom ISO to deploy my own applications

Tags: apache2, iso, docker, webmin

I need to create my custom ISO which will have my applications installed. My application is bind9 based and have webserver installed which holds that application.

Can someone guide me pls to achieve this in a better way? I also need to have below components or deb packages pre-installed.

ELK stack
Webmin
Docker-ce
apache2
nginx

Comment: Not sure it's what you're asking for but you can use clonezilla to clone your system and get a bootable iso. There are some extra steps required to make it boot on every machine properly (otherwise they'd all appear as the original machine on the web). Details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2868 in the cloning part.

Comment: take a look at docker and run it in a container.. with additional configs you can bring your machine up in no time